# Using cfhttp with unsplash api is showing a "Received fatal alert: protocol version" error message

Tags: json, coldfusion, cfhttp

I am connecting to the unsplash api (it allows free images to be used in websites) and the problem is that up until today everything was working fine. The user would enter a keyword and it was then sent using the following code:

```
<cfhttp url="https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos" method="get" result="fetchSplash">
    <cfhttpparam type="url" name="client_id" value="xxx">
    <cfhttpparam type="url" name="query" value="#url.unsplashme#">
    <cfhttpparam type="url" name="page" value="1">
    <cfhttpparam type="url" name="per_page" value="20">
</cfhttp>
```

JSON was being sent back with image information without any problems but now I get the following error:

[image]

I'm at a loss as to what the problem could be as nothing has changed on our server and if I test their url like this in a browser I get results ((ID number has been removed):

https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?client_id=xxx&page=1&query=office

Any help appreciated!

Comment: This is normally due to TLS support. Either the endpoint doesn’t support the TLS version you are handshaking with or your server doesn’t support the TLS version the endpoint expects. What version of Coldfusion and Java are you running? Have either of these been updated since the error started?

Comment: it's Coldfusion 10 and Java version 1.7.0_15. Everything was working fine this morning but when I went back to it this afternoon its throwing up those errors, nothing has been updated on the server.